# Eclipse Plugin - Save & Launch Dialog

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, editor, launcher

I'm developing a plugin with a editor and launcher.

When using Eclipse with java, if we try to launch with a non-saved code open, a window "Save and Launch" is displayed.
That window allow to save the open code and launch.

I would like to add a similar window in my plugin.

I already know how to verify if a open code is "dirty", but will it be possible use this same window or I will have to implement a new one?

If it is possible...how can I call this window?

Sorry for the bad english, I am Brazilian :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [`DebugUITools.saveBeforeLaunch()`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/debug/ui/DebugUITools.html#saveBeforeLaunch%28%29). Depending on the preferences, this will then either show the dialog or automatically save the dirty files.

Comment: this method is deprecated, but reading the javadocs I figured out the solution.     I extended LaunchConfigurationDelegate and used the method "saveBeforeLaunch".   Thank you.

Comment: Great. Now I've also learned something new and can use that in a project of mine.